# creating a 3-column wordpress header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I know a fair amount of php and I back my html/css skills. What I DO NOT back is my wordpress skills. 
Im trying to create my 1st wordpress template using bootstrap 3 framework - I'm guessing I'm setting the bar quite high as *I could not see any tutorials covering what im trying to do (perhaps because it is not possible...? Should you know of any please post in comment)*

**What I want to do**

Create a **3-column header** for a WordPress theme

**Here is an example of header I'm trying to create**

[image]

***I'm looking for a bit of advise on how to tackle this problem*** - keeping in mind I'm specifically after a 3-column header, where each columns content can easily be changed in back-end

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create your three columns and make each column a widgetized area. The widgets could then be edited individually in the Widgets area (under Appearance->Widgets).

[Here's some documentation on how you'd create a widgetized area.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create your three columns and make each column a widgetized area. The widgets could then be edited individually in the Widgets area (under Appearance->Widgets).

[Here's some documentation on how you'd create a widget area.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

Creating the 3-columns containers is then very easy with using bootstrap. See the first example below.

**Example one**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding the widget areas so that you can edit the contents from the back-end is like in the second example below, pretty simple.

**Example two**

```
<!--
  Get the widget sidebar for creating and editing the content.
  Customize the content by going to: wp-admin -> Appearance -> 
  Widgets -> content 1
!-->
 <?php get_sidebar('content'); ?>
```

Do make sure that you've registered all of the sidebars in functions.php and made templates for them.

**Full example**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php get_sidebar('content-1'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php get_sidebar('content-2'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php get_sidebar('content-3'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my last advice would be to when you've registered the sidebars (widget areas) is to, from the back-end, add text blocks to the widgets since you can also use html in these blocks and give them classes for creating the lay-out inside the blocks